# Ive already compiled the Apache Spark project , but has a nullification when using the debugger.

Tags: java, python, apache-spark

Im trying to debug one of the example modules named **JavaSparkPi.java** using the maven configurations.

The debuggers command line is **avro:protocol** and the compilation went successfully . 
 However,   when configuring a debugger in **MAVEN**, an error occurs.

```
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.jar.JarFile.close()`
```

The code is as follows :

```
package org.apache.spark.examples;

import org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util. scanner;

public final class JavaSparkPi {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 SparkSession spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("JavaSparkPi")
  .getOrCreate();

JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());

int slices = (args.length == 1) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 2;
int n = 100000 * slices;
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  l.add(i);
}

JavaRDD<Integer> dataSet = jsc.parallelize(l, slices);
int array.length (DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB);

int count = dataSet.map(integer -> {
  double x = Math.random() *3 - 1;
  double y = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  return (x * x + y * y <= 1) ? 1 : 0;
}).reduce((integer, integer2) -> integer + integer2);

System.out.println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n);

spark.stop();
}
}
```